# Windows 10 upgrade screwed Power Settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, windows-10-upgrade

Recently upgraded from 8.1 to 10. I had kept it for an overnight upgrade, and this was my undoing! When I checked in the morning, the PC was in sleep/hibernate mode and wouldn't wake up. I tried all different ways, and waited for ample time, to not take chance of interrupting any installation related thing.
Finally when nothing worked, had to do a hard restart. after which it told me (thankfully!) installation was successful, and personalization options were presented.
Since then, the power problem has persisted. When the PC sleeps, it cannot be awoken. I have kept sleep mode to after 5 hours as a brute force solution.
And it also does not shutdown fully. The power light and wifi light is on, does not go off. So I always have to do a hard shutdown, by longpress power button.
What can be done?

Already tried disabling the Fast Boot Option in Power Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the advanced power settings and change the setting *Turn of hard disk after* to *never*. Also under the *Sleep* setting, if *Hybrid Sleep* is an available option, you can try turning that off too.

[Here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2843-power-plan-settings-change-windows-10-a.html) are instructions are how to get to the advanced power plan settings in Windows 10. Lets us know the results! Good luck!

Comment: Tried the above. Didn't help.